# Changing Pentaho date values to first and last day of the week in Javascript Modified Value

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to set two variables to the first and last day of the week for a given date, but the .setDate() method does not seem to be changing the date and 'lastday' and 'firstday' variables return an Invalid Date (1970)

DateNew is from my input step which is defined as dd/MM/yyyy format

```
var curr = DateNew;
var first = getDayNumber(curr,"d") - getDayNumber(curr,"wm")
var last = first + 7;

var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toUTCString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the input variable as a date seemed to resolve the issue as there was no javascript type associated with it.

```
var curr = new Date(DateNew);
var first = getDayNumber(curr,"d") - getDayNumber(curr,"wm")
var last = first + 7;

var firstday = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
var lastday = new Date(curr.setDate(last)).toUTCString();
```